# Confusion regarding code puzzle-type question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, site-recommendation

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26933966/877472) was posted a few hours ago. As the title indicates, it is an coding challenge the OP was asked during an interview. The body of the post is an explanation of the challenge itself, but no actual question statement. Nor does it contain any attempted solution.

I was about to write a comment (as the OP appears to be new), and flag it to be moved to a more appropriate place, such as  [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf Stackexchange](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), when I noted that it, at the time of this post, had five upvotes and a couple of "favourites". Apparently it was previously closed as "too broad", and was later reopened after a rewording edit.

While I think its an interesting question itself, I'm very confused about how its being treated. To me, it really is more appropriate on an SE like codegolf. At the very least, it seems to violate the stipulation that questions should indicate a level of effort made to solve the problem.

Am I incorrect in my belief, and can anyone help me understand why this type of question is being favourably received?

Comment: *Side Note:* I struggled to find a way to word the last sentence that didn't sound disrespectful to the OP or the question - for clarification, by "favourably", I mean in regards to the number of upvotes, and the lack of comments suggestion it should be reposted on codegolf or some other SE (with the exception of one so far).

Comment: Heh. Yes, algorithm questions are on-topic, but I hate how people always use that as an excuse to just copy-paste problems like this that show absolutely **no** effort in solving the problem at all. That question is not on-topic.

Comment: @animuson That was my thought as well. I suppose I should have emphasised the lack of effort part, as that is significantly contributing to my confusion.

Comment: @animuson - So if the question is not on topic what is the correct close reason?

Comment: Do not assume that stars imply quality. They may just as well be used to follow trainwrecks, or bookmark bad questions to close later when one is out of close votes for the day.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Yup, agreed. Don't get me wrong, I'm not, or at least didn't mean to, imply that stars and upvotes always imply quality. But their very existence, and the lack of "what have you tried" comments and such made me wonder whether I was missing something. I myself have occasionally starred for the purpose of casting a close vote if the OP didn't later improved the question. And uhmm...admittedly starred a few trainwrecks too...

Answer (score 1):

Because SO has lots of people of all different levels and different knowledges of how SO works for them, just because it's starred wouldn't mean much unless SO was solely a site of nubes asking questions, Gurus answering them. But it's not, so sometimes nubes (like myself) like things for the wrong reasons. Or comment things for the wrong reasons, or write answers that are not - infact - answers,

The favourable receiving - in my eyes - does not make the question fit the rules of SO any more or less.

I know this isn't helpful but your question came across as saying that things that fit stack overflow policy should also be things that are upvoted and starred - and I see these two factors as possibly mutually exclusive.

Comment: To give a clearer answer - I think the question is favourably received because it causes people to think and is presented as a puzzle rather than as a problem. Regardless of how it fits the SO policy.

Comment: Regarding the last paragraph, I can see why you might think that. That wasn't my intention or meaning though. However, it is often typical for questions that don't typically fit within the SO paradigm to at least have a few comments indicating this (wouldn't necessarily have downvotes for that though). I would also expect comments asking the usual "what have you tried", to which there are presently none (and **that** would usually garner downvotes). I have also typically found that such questions usually get flagged and moved somewhat quickly (though of course this can vary greatly).

Comment: And in regards to the first paragraph, I think you are saying that users upvote and star things for a variety of reasons, not all of them would be "legitimate", and that this is possibly what's happening here? Second paragraph, I agree, a question is either a fit, or not. As animuson said, the fact that the OP has not indicated an attempt to solve the problem likely makes it "off topic" at this point.

Comment: From my personal approach the question is abstract from the user, it's just "a question" unrelated to any objective, and so I would expect the question to be marked as a discussion rather than a question, so perhaps a comment clarifying this to the OP would be a good way to go, ask them if they want a solution, and if so why, and if not they just want to discuss the puzzle.

Comment: I (or someone) will most likely do that in a bit. I wanted to make sure first that my reasoning was correct before doing that in case I was missing something or misunderstanding some SO policy.

Comment: Also I missed your first comment. Yes I agree, I also thought that was likely the reason for the upvotes. "Interesting" questions do typically get many upvotes, attention, etc.